# Improve speed for csv.reader/csv.writer in the csv module

Tags: performance, csv, python-3.x

I'm doing a pretty simple operation; opening a csv file, deleting the first column, and writing out to a new file.  The following code works fine, but it takes 50-60 seconds on my 700 MB file:

```
import csv
from time import time
#create empty output file
f = open('testnew.csv',"w")
f.close()
t = time()
with open('test.csv',"rt") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open('testnew.csv',"a") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            del r[0]
            _ = wtr.writerow( r )

print(round(time()-t))
```

By contrast, the following shell script does the same thing in 7-8 seconds:

```
START_TIME=$SECONDS
cut -d',' -f2- < test.csv > testnew.csv
echo $(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
```

Is there a way I can get comparable performance in Python?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the shell script is simply splitting lines at the first `,`, regardless of whether it is enclosed in quotes or not, and writing out the second part.  (I do not know what the shell script does if there is no `,`.)  The csv method does *much* more, which is useless for you.  To just do the same thing as the shell in python, skip the csv module.

```
for line in source:
   parts = line.split(',', maxsplit=1)
   source.write(parts[len(parts)-1])
```

This passes lines without a comma as is.  It leaves spaces after the comma (I do not know what `cut` does.  If you do not want that, you can either use `re.split` instead of `line.split` or add `.lstrip()` just before the closing `)` on the last line.

Comment: I wrapped your code sample with the relevant `with open` statements and replaced `source.write` with `_ = result.write`.  The resulting code still takes 30-40% longer than @histrio's solution.

Comment: The only important difference between my code and histrio's is handling the case of no ',' in the line.  If you are either sure that cannot happen or want an exception if it does, then go with the slightly simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

Your bash script not parse csv file, only split and cut. So, in python we can do the same:

```
with open('test.csv',"r") as source:
    with open('testnew.csv',"w") as result:
        for l in source:
            _, tail = l.split(',', 1)
            result.write(tail)
```

My simple profiling (4Mb file):

- bash - 193 ms
- python csv parsing - 2391 ms
- python string splitting - 620 ms

Python 2 is faster for some reason:

- bash - 193 ms
- python csv parsing - 1471 ms
- python string splitting - 373 ms

Comment: I'm getting comparable results, but with a `_=` before `result.write(tail)` to prevent it from printing the number of characters on each line.  So with my original file it still takes twice as much time as bash.

Comment: You can write C extension for this task :)